# Generate Core Data Sqlite Database on Server

Tags: json, core-data, sqlite, plist

I have an iPad app that uses Core Data with Sqlite. I keep getting errors when a save is called on the `managedobjectcontext`. The error is sql error (19) constraint fails. I found a few websites that lead me to modify my generation code and update the `Z_MAX` field in the table `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table. Are there any other things that Core Data does behind the scenes similar to this?

Note: Yes, I know I shouldn't be doing this but part of the problem is the core data database is over 5 MB and it takes a long time to process the data from a plist. (Maybe JSON would be faster?)

*EDIT* I just noticed Z_ENT which is the entity id. I have to add that into the generation as well.

*EDIT 2* Go the Entities mapped but I'm still getting the error. It is having trouble doing deletes and updates even through it appears to be valid.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared to just be an issue with the app itself.